# SIPのインストールが上手く行かないです。

Tags: python, pyqt

SIPのインストールが上手く行かないです。
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download
ここから、sip-4.19.8をダウンロード、展開し、そのディレクトリで

```
python configure.py --platform win32-g++
```

を実行したのち

```
make
```

を実行すると

```
make[1]: ディレクトリ `c:/Users/swall/python/sip-4.19.8/sipgen' に入ります
makefile:29: 警告: ターゲット `.c.o' へのコマンドを置き換えます
makefile:26: 警告: ターゲット `.c.o' への古いコマンドは無視されます
make[1]: `all' に対して行うべき事はありません.
make[1]: ディレクトリ `c:/Users/swall/python/sip-4.19.8/sipgen' から出ます
make[1]: ディレクトリ `c:/Users/swall/python/sip-4.19.8/siplib' に入ります
makefile:29: 警告: ターゲット `.c.o' へのコマンドを置き換えます
makefile:26: 警告: ターゲット `.c.o' への古いコマンドは無視されます
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o siplib.o siplib.c
In file included from C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/Python.h:65,
                 from siplib.c:20:
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:112:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:117:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
siplib.c: In function 'wrapInstance':
siplib.c:1653:42: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
         return sip_api_convert_from_type((void *)addr, wt->wt_td, NULL);
                                          ^
siplib.c: In function 'parsePass2':
siplib.c:5812:24: warning: 'enc' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
                     if (enc < 0)
                        ^
siplib.c:5708:32: warning: 'owner' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
                         *owner = arg;
                         ~~~~~~~^~~~~
siplib.c: In function 'slot_richcompare':
siplib.c:11320:52: warning: 'st' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     if ((f = (PyObject *(*)(PyObject *,PyObject *))findSlot(self, st)) == NULL)
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o apiversions.o apiversions.c
In file included from C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/Python.h:65,
                 from apiversions.c:20:
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:112:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:117:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o descriptors.o descriptors.c
In file included from C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/Python.h:65,
                 from descriptors.c:20:
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:112:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:117:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o qtlib.o qtlib.c
In file included from C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/Python.h:65,
                 from qtlib.c:21:
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:112:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:117:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o threads.o threads.c
In file included from C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/Python.h:65,
                 from sipint.h:24,
                 from threads.c:22:
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:112:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:117:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o objmap.o objmap.c
In file included from C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/Python.h:65,
                 from sipint.h:24,
                 from objmap.c:23:
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:112:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:117:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o voidptr.o voidptr.c
In file included from C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/Python.h:65,
                 from voidptr.c:20:
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:112:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:117:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o array.o array.c
In file included from C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/Python.h:65,
                 from array.c:20:
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:112:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:117:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o int_convertors.o int_convertors.c
In file included from C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/Python.h:65,
                 from int_convertors.c:38:
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:112:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\python\Python3.5.2\include/pytime.h:117:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
g++ -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\python\Python3.5.2\include -o bool.o bool.cpp
g++ -mthreads -Wl,-enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -shared -Wl,-subsystem,console -Wl,-s -o sip.pyd siplib.o apiversions.o descriptors.o qtlib.o threads.o objmap.o voidptr.o array.o int_convertors.o bool.o -LC:\python\Python3.5.2\libs -lpython35
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\python\Python3.5.2\libs/libpython35.a: error adding symbols: file format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [sip.pyd] エラー 1
make[1]: ディレクトリ `c:/Users/swall/python/sip-4.19.8/siplib' から出ます
make: *** [all] エラー 2
```

のようにエラーが出てきてしまいます。

python環境はvenvで作ったpython3.5.2です。

お力添えいただけますと幸いです。

(追記)
コマンドはcmd.exeで入力しています。
mingw32とGnuWin32をインストールしています。OSはwindows10 64ビットです。

Comment: `pip install PyQt5-sip==4.19.8` では駄目ということでしょうか？ ([過去質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59009/19110)を見るに、PyQt4が必要なのでしょうか)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。PyQt4が必要であるため、このような措置を取っています。

Comment: Windows環境のようなので、どの g++ をどの環境 (cmd.exe？Cygwin？等) でお使いなのかを追記して頂きたいです。リンカが libpython35.a のファイル形式を認識できていないというエラーが出ていますので、何かしら食い違っていそうです。

Comment: コマンドはcmd.exeで入力しています。GnuWinとWinGWをGnuWinインストールしています。

Comment: MinGWかMinGW-w64でしょうか？　他の方の助けにもなるので、「編集」から情報を追記して頂けると嬉しいです :)

Comment: ご丁寧に教えていただき、誠にありがとうございます。情報を追記いたしました。